# Apache2 ReverseProxy to Nginx Unit subfolder issues

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I want to configure a simple reverse proxy in Apache2 to play around with Nginx Unit

```
   <Location /nextcloud>
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /nextcloud http://127.0.0.1:7788
    ProxyPassReverse /nextcloud http://127.0.0.1:7788
```

Nginx Unit Configuration is successful

```
curl -X DELETE --unix-socket /var/run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config/
curl -X PUT --data-binary @config.json --unix-socket /var/run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config/
tail -n 20 /var/log/unit.log
```

Nginx Unit Nextcloud config example from here: https://unit.nginx.org/howto/nextcloud/

Works as intended, but I am having trouble telling Nginx Unit that the Application is to be served at the "/nextcloud" subfolder, calling https://localhost/nextcloud redirects to https://localhost/index.php

I am guessing this might be a problem inside the unit routes:

```
    "routes": [
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": [
                    "/build/*",
                    "/tests/*",
                    "/config/*",
                    "/lib/*",
                    "/3rdparty/*",
                    "/templates/*",
                    "/data/*",
                    "/.*",
                    "/autotest*",
                    "/occ*",
                    "/issue*",
                    "/indie*",
                    "/db_*",
                    "/console*"
                ]
            },

            "action": {
                "return": 404
            }
        },
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": [
                    "/core/ajax/update.php*",
                    "/cron.php*",
                    "/index.php*",
                    "/ocm-provider*.php*",
                    "/ocs-provider*.php*",
                    "/ocs/v1.php*",
                    "/ocs/v2.php*",
                    "/public.php*",
                    "/remote.php*",
                    "/status.php*",
                    "/updater*.php*"
                ]
            },

            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/nextcloud/direct"
            }
        },
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": "/ocm-provider*"
            },

            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/nextcloud/ocm"
            }
        },
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": "/ocs-provider*"
            },

            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/nextcloud/ocs"
            }
        },
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": "/updater*"
            },

            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/nextcloud/updater"
            }
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "share": "/var/www/nextcloud-test/nextcloud-files$uri",
                "fallback": {
                    "pass": "applications/nextcloud/index"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Did someone already have some experiences of direct an nginx unit hosted application to a subfolder?

Nextcloud wise configuration has been adjusted

```
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://localhost/nextcloud',
  'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
  'overwritehost' => 'localhost',
  'overwritewebroot' => '/nextcloud',
```